# Merge the two different JSON using node JS

Tags: json

I have two requests that return their data as JSON using NodeJS Seriate.

The first response is:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": {
                "expand": "renderedFields,names,schem,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
                "id": "64672",
                "self": "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/64672",
                "key": "CKS-2016",
                "fields": {
                    "parent": {
                        "id": "64670",
                        "key": "CKS-2014"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The second response is:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
        "errors": [],
        "detail": [
            {
                "repositories": [
                    {
                        "name": "registry",
                        "avatar": "http://stash.computenext.com/projects/SERVICES/avatar.png?s=32",
                        "avatarDescription": "services"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to merge the two responses, that would have the following structure:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": {
                "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
                "id": "64672",
                "self": "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/64672",
                "key": "CKS-2016",
                "fields": {
                    "parent": {
                        "id": "64670",
                        "key": "CKS-2014",
                        "detail": [
                            {
                                "repositories": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "registry",
                                        "avatar": "http://stash.computenext.com/projects/SERVICES/avatar.png?s=32",
                                        "avatarDescription": "services"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I searched and found several methods of joining or extending two JSON objects but nothing similar to that.

How can I achieve this?

My Actual Code is,

```
exports.getIssues = function(req, res) {
    console.log(filename + '>>get Issues>>');
    var response = {
        status : Boolean,
        message : String,
        data : String
    };
    var request = require('request');
    var username = const.username ;
    var password = const.password ;
    var options = {
        url : 'https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=status+%3D+Resolved+ORDER+BY+updated',
        auth : {
            username : username,
            password : password
        }
    };

    request( options, function(error, obj) {
                if (error) {
                    response.message = appmsg.DATA_NT_FOUND;
                    response.status = false;
                    response.data = obj;
                    res.send(response);
                } else {
                     response.message = appmsg.DATA_FOUND;
                     response.status = true;
                     response.data = JSON.parse(obj.body);
                     //res.send(response);
                    var issueKey = response.data.issues;

                    // var keyData = issueKey[0].key;
                    // console.log(response.data.issues);
                    // console.log(keyData);
                    var output = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < issueKey.length; i++) {
                        var issue = issueKey[i].key;
                        //var key = [];
                        //key.push(issue);
                        console.log(issue);

                        var respon = {
                            status : Boolean,
                            message : String,
                            data : String
                        };
                            var request = require('request'),
                                username = const.username ,
                                password = const.username ,
                                url = "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/" + issue,
                                auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

                            //console.log(url);
                            request({url : url,headers : {"Authorization" : auth}}, function(err, object){
                                if (object) {

                                        var info = object;
                                        output.push(info); // this is not working as ouput is undefined at this    point
                                        //var pout = JSON.parse(output);
                                        //console.log(info);
                                        console.log("==============================================================================");
                                        //console.log(output);
                                        console.log("******************************************************************************");
                                            if(issueKey.length === output.length){
                                                respon.message = appmsg.DATA_FOUND;
                                                respon.status = true;
                                                respon.data = output;
                                                //console.log(output);
                                                //res.send(respon);


                                                  var id = issueKey[0].id;
                                                  console.log(id);

                                                   var commitout = [];
                                                    for(var i = 0; i < issueKey.length; i++) {
                                                        var commits = issueKey[i].id;
                                                        console.log(commits);



                                                      var request = require('request'),
                                                      username = const.username ,
                                                      password = const.password ,
                                                      url = "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/dev-status/1.0/issue/detail?issueId=" + commits + "&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository",
                                                      auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

                                                    //console.log(url);
                                                    var test = [];
                                                    request({url : url,headers : {"Authorization" : auth}}, function(err, obj1){
                                                      if (obj1) {

                                                              var info1 = obj1.body;
                                                              commitout.push(info1);
                                                              if(issueKey.length === commitout.length){
                                                                respon.message = appmsg.DATA_FOUND;
                                                                respon.status = true;
                                                                respon.data = commitout;
                                                                // console.log(commitout);
                                                                  //var test = merge(output, commitout);

                                                                  var text = output.body;
                                                                  var resultdone = output;

                                                                  resultdone.data = resultdone + commitout.body;

                                                                  console.log(resultdone.data);


                                                                res.send(resultdone.data);
                                                              }
                                                            }
                                                   });
                                                  }

                                    }
                                }

                        });

                }
            }

        });
```

};

> How can i merge the two arrays? in one response. That is my question..

Comment: inside body is that is valid json , i check that is not valid json . or its just string. Is that is the excact thing you are getting or you have added sort `body`

Comment: That is string..... how can i sort it ??? Please help me.

Comment: I tried your code. Not getting any correct response. Give me a right solution and check my above code once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

var result1 =

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": {
                "expand": "renderedFields,names,schem,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
                "id": "64672",
                "self": "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/64672",
                "key": "CKS-2016",
                "fields": {
                    "parent": {
                        "id": "64670",
                        "key": "CKS-2014"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

var text = result1.data[0].body;

var result2 =

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
        "errors": [],
        "detail": [
            {
                "repositories": [
                    {
                        "name": "registry",
                        "avatar": "http://stash.computenext.com/projects/SERVICES/avatar.png?s=32",
                        "avatarDescription": "services"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

var resultdone = result1;

resultdone.data[0].body.fields.parent=  result2.body.detail;

Comment: @Jivi Does that give you solution ?

Comment: Don't manipulate the JSON through string manipulation... parse the structure first.

Comment: I ask her wheather it is string or json she said string . Any also when i parse string that was not right json . I will update answer for json also

Comment: What is the issue . It should work . What error you are getting now? . If they are two json object you can do like this.

Comment: There is no errors in that. But am not getting the expected results.

Comment: I have "n" number of objects in result1 body & "n" number of objects in result2 body. How can do that??

Comment: Ask the question again . What you want and what you want to achieve ? The question you have ask is changed many time .That is not the way to question .

Comment: The question is, how can i merge the req 2 array in req 1 array.

Answer (score 1):

Never mainpulate the string of JSON directly.  Parse it first.

```
const firstRes = JSON.parse(firstResJson);
const secondRes = JSON.prase(secondResJson);
```

Now, it's a bit unclear what you want to do, and why you want to do it, but try this:

```
firstRes.data.body.fields.parent.detail = secondRes.body.detail;
```

Then, you'll find your combined data in `firstRes`.  To get it back to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(firstRes);
```

Comment: I tried your code. JSON.parse throws an error like "json at position 10". Please check my code.

Comment: @Jivi Check your JSON, and learn to read what an error message says to debug what's going on.

Comment: How can i merge is my questn?

Comment: @Jivi I showed you how, but your problem is with your JSON syntax apparently.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj1  = {
"status": true,
"message": "Data Found",
"data": [
    {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": {
            "expand": "renderedFields,names,schem,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
            "id": "64672",
            "self": "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/64672",
            "key": "CKS-2016",
            "fields": {
                "parent": {
                    "id": "64670",
                    "key": "CKS-2014"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]};


var obj2 = {
"statusCode": 200,
"body": {
    "errors": [],
    "detail": [
        {
            "repositories": [
                {
                    "name": "registry",
                    "avatar": "http://stash.computenext.com/projects/SERVICES/avatar.png?s=32",
                    "avatarDescription": "services"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}
   }


  obj1.data.forEach(function(item, index){
      item.body.fields.parent.detail = r.body.detail[index];
  });

  console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: Can you check my code once and give the correct solution. Please ?